# Fill more than one column with SELECT in statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I would like to ask how can I insert data into a more than one column at the same time if I have an `SELECT` statement in an `INSERT` statement. I want to fill the following table:

```
|-------------------|-----------------|--------------|-----------------|
|     TableName     |     ColName     |     Value    |  SQL_Statement  |
|-------------------|-----------------|--------------|-----------------|
```

I have following query which is only filing a Value column:

```
SET @SQL_String = 'INSERT INTO #ResultTable(Value) SELECT ' + @ColName + ' FROM ' + @TableSchema + '.' + @TableName + ' WHERE ' + @ColName + ' = ''' + cast(@GuidArgument AS NVARCHAR(50)) + '''';
```

I need to fill all the columns but I don't know how to write that query. Here is some "pseudocode" of a query I need:

```
INSERT INTO TableSchema
    (
    TableName,
    ColName, 
    Value, 
    SQL_Statement
    ) 
VALUES 
    (
    @TableName, 
    @ColName, 
    [THAT LONG SELECT FROM QUERY ABOVE], 
    @SQL_Statement
    );
```

Please consider that I'm using a dynamic query.

Thank you all!

PS: It wasn't so easy to summarize my request, any edits are really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change your **@SQL_String** expression, we can achieve this the following way.
I hope this is that you are expecting.

```
SET @SQL_String=
N'INSERT INTO #ResultTable
    (
    TableName,
    ColName, 
    Value, 
    SQL_Statement
    ) 
SELECT
    '+@TableName+', 
    '+@ColName+', 
    (SELECT ' + @ColName + ' FROM ' + @TableSchema + '.' + @TableName + ' WHERE ' + @ColName + ' = ''' + cast(@GuidArgument AS NVARCHAR(50)) + '''),
    '''+@SQL_Statement+''''
```

Comment: I'm trying to work this out. But it is giving me a few errors:

`Incorrect syntax near ','.`

`Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '304596F2-E213-4F47-9816-0000758369BF',);'.`

`Incorrect syntax near '304596F2-E213-4F47-9816-0000758369BF',);'.`

Comment: I have updated my answer. There is one extra quote which i have removed. Please try now @Chyu

Comment: Now there is twice error saying: `Incorrect syntax near ','.`.
I'm trying to resolve your query too.

Comment: Yes you are correct. Problem is first select should not have parenthesis and select should be put inside parenthesis. I have update the answer accordingly. Please try now @Chyu

Comment: The first `SELECT` is not needed to be in parenthesis? Now it is giving: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.`.

Comment: Yes after first SELECT paranthesis shouldn't be there. and the next SELECT should be put inside parenthesis. Please check my updated answer for the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178127/discussion-between-chyu-and-trinadh).

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use the `VALUES` keyword here. When you want to select a value from a table to insert it, you must use `insert into .. select ..` Something like that:

```
Insert INTO TableName 
       (col1, 
        col2, 
        col3, 
        col4)
Select 'AStaticValue', 
       'AnotherStaticValue', 
        col1, 
        col4
FROM    AnotherTable 
WHERE   SomeCondition = true
```

So in your case, it should look something like:

```
INSERT INTO TableSchema
    (
    TableName,
    ColName, 
    Value, 
    SQL_Statement
    ) 
Select
    @TableName, 
    @ColName, 
    ColumnNameFromYourQuery, 
    @SQL_Statement
From your-table where condition;
```

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to run two queries :

1) SELECT query

```
SET @SQL_String = 'INSERT INTO #ResultTable(Value) SELECT ' + @ColName + ' FROM ' + @TableSchema + '.' + @TableName + ' WHERE ' + @ColName + ' = ''' + cast(@GuidArgument AS NVARCHAR(50)) + '''';
```

2) UPDATE query

```
UPDATE TableSchema
SET  TableName=  @TableName, ColName= @ColName, SQL_Statement= @SQL_Statement
WHERE SQL_Statement=@SQL_Statement;
```

Comment: OP doesn't want to `update` his table. He wants to actually `insert` data into that table.

Comment: It's not actually updating. First you insert to the table then update means actually inserting to the same row that contains the correct SQL_Statement. Update is same as Insert. We call it update because it follows INSERT statement.

Answer (score 0):

Add static value to your `SELECT` query :

```
INSERT INTO TableSchema
SELECT @TableName
    ,@ColName
    ,col1
    ,col2
    ,colX
FROM WhateverTable
WHERE some_column = 'some_value'
```